# Code Optimization | Faster methodology than dataframe.iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I currently have some working code that loops through a pandas dataframe using df.iterrows(), but am looking to optimize it (either using df.apply() or switching to numpy arrays). I'm just not able to wrap my head around how I'd be able to do this. Code/data below:

**Data:**

```
raw_text                  tokenized_text
hello, my name is tom     [hello, my, name, is, tom]
hello, my name is jeff    [hello, my, name, is, jeff]
```

**Problem To Solve:**
Compare the tokenized_text column to a list and count the number of overlapping words between the tokenized_text column and the list. Code below:

**Code:**

```
def list_compare(lst1, lst2):
        freq = len(list(set(lst1) & set(lst2)))
        return freq

lst = ['hello', 'my']
freq_counts = []

for val in df.iterrows():
    freq_counts.append(list_compare(lst, val[1][tokenized_text])

df['freq_counts'] = freq_counts
```

**Question:**
Is there a faster way to do what I'm doing above using the apply() function or numpy arrays?

Thanks!

Comment: How likely is it that you have matrixes of same length? The speed can be _really_ improved if that's the case.

Comment: @rafaelc 100%, they'll always be the same length

Comment: `DataFrame.iterrrows` and `Series.apply` are both slow loops. Perhaps one has slightly less overhead than the other, but in my experience quibbling over that isn't worth the gain that you would get using a more vectorized solution, or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `apply` with `set` intersection:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"raw_text":["hello, my name is tom","hello, my name is jeff"]})
df["tokenized_text"] = df["raw_text"].str.findall("\w+")

lst = ['hello', 'my']

df["count"] = df["tokenized_text"].apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(set(lst))))

print (df)

#
                 raw_text               tokenized_text  count
0   hello, my name is tom   [hello, my, name, is, tom]      2
1  hello, my name is jeff  [hello, my, name, is, jeff]      2
```

Comment: Worked, accepted, thank you! One question: Any downside/upside to using a lambda function vs. abstracting it out as it's own function?

Comment: Upside is you saved yourself a `def func...` :)